# Site selection drop-down offer already pinned sites to be pinned

Tags: discussion, android-app

With the Android app, open the sidebar then click on *Edit* near *Your sites* to open the menu of pinned sites.

This open this page:

> [image: Your Sites]

Clicking on the bottom arrow opens a list to add sites to the list of pinned sites:

> [image: Select a site to pin]

See how Stack Overflow (and other sites) are present in both images? Why does the app offer to add Stack Overflow (and others) if it's already in the *Your Sites* list?

Comment: Thanks for the update ChrisForrence.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue is present on web. This makes me think it may be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

However, sites already in "your sites" are given a darker, shaded background.To be consistent, a similar behavior should be used in the apps.