# Why does the "meta" option of one of the sites I am member of not appear in the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, bug, android-app, communities-list

I am currently a member of six Stack Exchange sites, namely Stack Overflow, Super User, Information Security, Unix and Linux, Cryptography, Android Enthusiasts. And I have the privilege to participate in meta of Stack Overflow, Super User and Information Security, but the problem is:
Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Super User are appearing in "My sites" options in the app, but Meta Information Security is not appearing.

Why is this happening?

Here is the Screenshot shot of Android app:

[image]

Comment: Might be a bug.

Comment: Have you edited the list yourself?

Comment: @Cai yes, of course

Comment: @daya so did you add the sites you say are missing?

Comment: @Cai how can I add a meta site to my list. It should get automatically added once I got enough rep.

Comment: @daya no, if you've edited the list only sites you manually add to the list will be shown there. I have *no* meta sites in my list.

Comment: @Cai I can't understand why you have no meta sites in your list and the clear thing is I never added a meta site manually (not possible to add) except the main sites.

Comment: @daya I don't have any meta sites because I don't *want* any meta sites. If I did, I'd add them. You can add meta sites just as you do main sites.

Comment: @Cai I can't ,  there will be no search results if you would search "meta information security" in search bar.

Comment: @Cai Oh! I didn't saw the "meta information security" in previous search because I didn't scrolled down! Sorry, to waste your time.

Comment: Now I added that missing site and This was not a bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list, by default, lists the top 10 (I believe?) sites you have an account on in order of your reputation on those sites...

If you've edited the list then *only the sites you manually add* are shown in the list, ordered in the order you set them to... So if you want a meta site as well as the main site in the list you need to manually add *both* sites (adding a main site *won't* automatically add it's corresponding meta).

You can edit the list in any of the apps or on the website and it will sync between them. To edit the list on the app you need to hit "EDIT" at the top of the list, you can then use the search bar to search for the sites you want to add (you need to tap the arrow on the search bar to expand the list and may need to scroll through the list to find the site you want to add.).

> [image]

<sup>Image taken from here (since I don't have an Android device to hand):
[Site selection drop-down offer already pinned sites to be pinned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230134/307988)</sup>

Comment: Well, I agree "adding a main site won't automatically add it's corresponding meta" but it would get automatically added when you get enough rep. I am pretty sure that I never added meta StackOverflow and meta SuperUser and it's get automatically added after some rep.

Comment: But i don't know why it doesn't happened with Information Security meta when I got enough rep on main site.

Comment: Now the another question arises is: why we get notified that "you have earned privilege to participate in meta" ? If anybody can add a meta site manually without a privilege barrier.

Comment: @daya sites are added automatically *before* you manually edit the list yourself; once you edit the list it stops being automatically updated and becomes a manual list.

Comment: You can add *any* sites (even sites you don't have an account on) to the list. It's basically a place to bookmark sites, nothing more (so reputation doesn't really matter)